# maven with JDK11: javac: invalid flag: --release

Tags: java, maven, java-11, maven-toolchains-plugin

I'm trying to set up a simple maven project with java 11. As I want to keep JAVA_HOME to be version 8, I'm using `maven-toolchains-plugin` to make maven use jdk11 for this project.

While maven successfully finds a matching toolchain for jdk-11.0.1, I keep getting " javac: invalid flag: --release". What am I doing wrong?

Here are the plugin configurations:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <release>11</release>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>toolchain</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <toolchains>
        <jdk>
          <version>11</version>
        </jdk>
      </toolchains>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

The toolchain is defined as:

```
 <toolchain>
   <type>jdk</type>
   <provides>
     <version>11</version>
     <id>JavaSE-1.11</id>
   </provides>
   <configuration>
     <jdkHome>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin</jdkHome>
   </configuration>
<toolchain>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I found out, the configuration is just fine. The problem was that `jdkHome` in `toolchains.xml` was pointing to the `\jdk-11.0.1\bin` direction instead of `\jdk-11.0.1` directly..... Using `<jdkHome>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1</jdkHome>` solves the problem..

Answer (score 4):

Changing the jdk version should fix the problem mostly. Replace

```
<version>1.11</version>
```

with

```
<version>11</version>
```

Do ensure though that your maven is configured with JDK-11 using the command `mvn -version` and confirming the Java version there. You can also verify the `toolchains.xml` JDK configured as well.

---

In case you're trying to compile using different versions of the compiler, you need to ensure executions under the `maven-compiler-plugin` as:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>java11</id>
        <phase>none</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <release>11</release>
            <jdkToolchain>
                <version>11</version>
            </jdkToolchain>
            <compileSourceRoots>
                <compileSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/java11</compileSourceRoot>
            </compileSourceRoots>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/versions/11</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Here is the [sample `pom.xml`](https://github.com/meterware/multirelease-parent/blob/master/pom.xml) referred for the above.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. As you can see, I want to use a different jdk version (11) than java_home (8), which is the reason why I am using toolchain.xml to make maven use a different jdk for this project. Changing the version of the toolchain from 1.11 to 11 does not solve the problem.

Comment: @HengruiJiang Did you configure the `executions` in compiler plugin as well?

Comment: As I found out, the reason for failing was that I pointed jdkHome to the bin folder instead of directly to jdk.... *hideface* Thx for the help though!

Comment: @HengruiJiang I meant something similar with ... *Do ensure though that your maven is configured with JDK-11*